# prevent commit to specific branch

Tags: github, branch

I want to prevent commit to test branch. Only another branch should be merged into test branch. Test branch sould not accept commit directly.
I shouldn't solve it using git hooks. Can I do it from Github interface? I couldn't find it Github's settings.

Comment: It is one of the settings in github where you _protect_ the branch and you specify that you only want to bring changes through pull requests. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches

Comment: You cannot stop me from committing to any branch name I like, because I *make commits* using *my* branch names in *my* repository. What you can do using GitHub's "protected branch" feature is *stop me from using `git push` to send commits to **your** branch in **your** GitHub repository.*

Comment: It's crucial that you understand the difference between me making a commit—which is something I do on the privacy of my own computer—and me *asking* GitHub to put my new commits into *your* repository over there. That's not "making a commit"—I have to have already *made* the commits in question.